# MatPlotLab and bargraphing a csv file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to convert a csv file into a bar graph, but I only want to use the each individual row as a data set. I want to make a bar graph. I need to create individual bars for each month that represent their value for that month, however I keep getting conversion errors.
[This is the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kloOM.jpg)

This is the code I have,

```
  >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('11m2015.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows = (0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), usecols = range(1,7))
data = data.transpose()

xt = np.loadtxt('11m2015.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',', skiprows = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), usecols = range(1,7))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('11m2015.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows = 1, usecols = range(1,7))
data = data.transpose()

xt = np.loadtxt('11m2015.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',', usecols = range(1,7))



width = 0.45
ind = np.arange(7) + 0.75


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
p0 = ax.bar(ind, data[0],  width, color = 'cyan')


ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_xlabel('month')
ax.set_xticks (ind + width/2.)
ax.set_xticklabels( xt, rotation = 70 )

fig.legend( (p0[0]))
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()

width = 0.45
ind = np.arange(7) + 0.75


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
p0 = ax.bar(ind, data[0],  width, color = 'cyan')


ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_xlabel('month')
ax.set_xticks (ind + width/2.)
ax.set_xticklabels( xt, rotation = 70 )

fig.legend( (p0[0]))
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Comment: `however I keep getting conversion errors` -> please add all relevant error tracebacks to your question.

Comment: if you get conversion errors then they are probably related to `np.loadtxt` and not to barcharts or matplotlib. The title is thus very misleading. For problemsolving. Please first remove all the plotting stuff and try to load your data correctly. If there is an error, please report the line in which it occurs. But also first try to solve it yourself by changing the `delimiter`, `skiprows`,  `usecols`arguments. Be aware that you cannot easily load strings/text into a numpy array. Also consider to use `np.genfromtxt`.